# Python: interactive shell, easy way to save and load data

Tags: python

I am using interactive python:

**Short example:**

```
$python
$>>> a = 1
$>>> b = 2
$>>> c = a+b
$>>>
```

With R, we can `save.image("x.Rdata")` and `load("x.Rdata")` easily for next time to use.

With Python, is there a similar way? Or any easy way?
Thanks.

Comment: use [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) instead of Python Shell and you will be able to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module that's built into Python to accomplish that

```py
import pickle

myvariable = [1,2,3]

with open('variable.pickle', 'wb+') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(myvariable, outfile)

newvariable = None

with open('variable.pickle', 'rb+') as infile:
    newvariable = pickle.load(infile)
```